# How to explicitly disallow a `.dir-locals` file ever from being loaded or queried about?

Tags: directory-local-variables, load

If I have a `.dir-locals` file that is meant as a template. How can I avoid the annoyance of being asked about whether or not the values are safe to load every time I open the file? I do want not to disable checking safe values for all `.dir-locals` files, just specific ones which I do not want.

Comment: I suggest *not* naming it `.dir-locals.el`

Comment: That's what I actually ended up doing shortly after I posted this.